# Microsoft Recommendation Sockets

Tags: c#, sockets

```
// message buffer
Byte[] dataByte = new Byte[RES_SIZE]; 
int readedBytes = 0; 

do // wait....
{ 
    Thread.Sleep(Delay); 
    message = string.Format("Waiting for messages, check number #{0}", readedBytes); 

} while (!networkStream.DataAvailable); 
//
// check for message
if (networkStream.DataAvailable)
{ 
    readedBytes = networkStream.Read(dataByte, 0, RES_SIZE); 
    //...
    //...
    //...
}
```

I have a document with Microsoft Recommendation about previous code, that is:

---

*This code explicitly relies on the NetworkStream.DataAvailable property. While this is not incorrect, it is 
not very efficient, as it forces the code to test this property in a loop with nested Thread.Sleep() calls, 
which can increase the number of thread Context Switches / second, and could lead to somewhat 
increased CPU usage.*

Furthermore, this does not mean that the Socket.ReceiveTimeout value isn’t being used, since the socket is configured in blocking mode, and thus the NetworkStream.Read() call can potentially block anyway.

A second issue with the code above is that it assumes that a single Read() operation will read the entire host response. While this can be true for small reads, this is **not** guaranteed by the Socket API, and could potentially lead to partial reads.

This will be very hard to handle if the data connector does not have inside knowledge of the host communication protocol, as it would require being able to interpret the data read from the socket to detect if the response message was read completely.

Also, if partial reads were to happen, this could cause significant problems once Connection Pooling is introduced. Consider the following scenario:

- A transaction on the website obtains a new connection from the pool and sends a request to the host.
- The host replies with a 1526 byte response.
- The Connection object tries to read from the socket, but only reads 1345 bytes.
- Since the connection believe it has read the entire response from the socket, it returns the connection to the pool and continues.

Now, imagine what happens when a second transaction on the website comes along, asks for a 
connection from the pool and gets the same connection used in the first case:

- The code gets the connection from the pool and sends a new request message to the host
- The host replies with a new 1520 by response
- The connection attempts to read from the socket and gets 1701 bytes back.

That is, it gets the remaining 181 bytes that were not originally read during the first call, as well as the 
complete response from the second operation. This will probably cause an error when the caller attempts 
to parse the host response and finds it to be malformed.

**Recommendation**
It is strongly recommended to avoid relying on Socket reads reading entire messages sent by the host, 
while this will happen most of the time under normal circumstances, this can easily break under load or 
network congestion.

---

**With this introduction, I have been searching how to resolve this issue, however, all examples use the same solution that I used.**

```
do // wait....
{
    //
    //
    //
} while (!networkStream.DataAvailable);
```

Question:
How I to fix this issue?

Comment: In addition, a while loop on `DataAvailable` is good for almost any stream except a Network stream, because you will almost always read faster than all the bytes are sent.

Comment: @Silvermind Thread.Sleep really ensures CPU load is increased, by forcing a context switch.

Comment: @ElCote where did you get this "Microsoft recommendation" document?  Thread.Sleep is almost always the wrong way to do it.

Comment: @PeterRitchie, That was not what I meant, but I could have been more clear about that. Without `Thread.Sleep` in this context, it would eat more cpu than with the Thread.Sleep. Whether it is a good idea to use it, was not the issue in my comment. I was regarding: _and could lead to somewhat increased CPU usage._ as in opposed to this loop without it.

Comment: I would recommend using asynchronous IO rather than polling.  I find it hard to believe anything from Microsoft recommends polling for data on a socket.

Comment: @PeterRitchie A Microsoft engineer visited our offices

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the SELECT method in socket. It takes a list of sockets and returns those having data available.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.select(v=vs.110).aspx

This allows you to have one loop checking x sockets and then handle the ones with data in separate threads / tasks.

http://books.google.pl/books?id=2zT5b2BS1OUC&pg=PA96&lpg=PA96&dq=socket.select+example+c%23&source=bl&ots=_JZzZY1zzQ&sig=AnGpQbL_GP2MR3Yk4oHNzJAqwU4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fGgXU-frDorLsgas_YDwCw&ved=0CDwQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=socket.select%20example%20c%23&f=false

actually has some good discussion on that. It is an excerpt from the book "TCP/IP Sockets in C#: Practical Guide for Programmers".